# Value returns by unwind is "null"

Tags: ios, objective-c

i try to use an unwind method to return the value of a row (from a table ) in another view 
but the value catch in the first viewController is null.

This is the code in FirstViewController

```
- (IBAction)retrievePremadeMessage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;(h)
- (IBAction)retrievePremadeMessage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
PreStoredMessagesTableViewController *cc = segue.sourceViewController;
self.textViewMsg = [[UITextView alloc] init];
self.textViewMsg.text = cc.valeurCell;
NSLog(@"cell selected: %@", cc.valeurCell);
}
```

and this is the secondViewController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Retrieve the value of cell selected
self.valeurCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text];
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// Retrieve the value of cell selected
self.valeurCell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text];
}
```

Add:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text]];
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *stringPassedIn = id;
}
```

Comment: the segue "identifier" link the tableViewCell with the ohter UIViewController or what exactly it does? Thanks

Comment: @dev99 In Interface Builder when you Control Click and drag from one ViewController to another creates a segue. Push Segues are for when your views are managed by a UINavigationController and modal segues are for modally presenting the next view. When you Control click and drag from one ViewController to the next it will create an arrow. Here you can change the type in the far right pane of XCode; also you can specify the identifier. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html)

Comment: Sorry, is a good answer, i was searching for the solution somewhere else and i didn't see your reply. Thanks.